# Understanding Elements of Hardy Spaces

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analytic-functions, hardy-spaces

As I was reading HARDY SPACES $H^p$, It's definition clearly states that it is the space of analytic functions on a unit disc satisfying norm conditions.

I didn't get that ,the texts say that $H^p$ is a subset of $L^p$ , How is that even possible because $L^p$ is a collection of equivalence classes.

Kindly help! 
Thanx n regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author is abusing notation a bit. Given any $H^p$ function $F: \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{C}$, you can look at the associated boundary value function $f : S^1 \to \mathbb{C}$ given by $f(\zeta) = \lim_{z \to \zeta} F(z)$ where the limit here is taken non-tangentially (I'm sure your book discusses this). The point is that this $f$ is in $L^p$, and the association $F \mapsto f$ is injective. So, we can basically view $H^p$ as a subset of $L^p$.

Comment: I got it but how can you say that  f will be in $L^p$.@mathworker21

Comment: You can show that $F_r \to f$ in $L^p$ as $r \uparrow 1$, which will imply that $f$ is in $L^p$. Here $F_r: S^1 \to \mathbb{C}, F_r(\theta) = F(re^{i\theta})$. Your book should have proved this result...